# CalDAV Request To gGt iCloud Calendar Events

Tags: calendar, icalendar, webdav, caldav

I am trying to build an HTTP request to get events from an iCloud Calendar. I can get the details of a calendar (via PROPFIND) and get the details of a single calendar event via its event id (GET), but cannot write a request which returns calendar events within a specified time range.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong in the code below? The only response I get is (code 207). There is a single event in the calendar within the timeframe set.

```
<multistatus xmlns="DAV:"/>
```

From:

```
REPORT /<ICLOUD_USER_ID>/calendars/<ICLOUD_CALENDAR_ID>/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic <AUTHDATA>
Depth: 2
Prefer: return-minimal
Host: p31-caldav.icloud.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.2.2 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.2) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 367

<c:calendar-query xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:c="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">      
    <d:prop>
        <c:calendar-data />
    </d:prop>
    <c:filter>        
        <c:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
            <c:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
                <c:time-range start="20160524T000000Z" end="20160526T000000Z" />
            </c:comp-filter>
        </c:comp-filter>
     </c:filter>
</c:calendar-query>
```

Thanks in advance,

Jamie

---

Edit: The get request that does work:

Request:

```
GET /<ICLOUD_USER_ID>/calendars/<ICLOUD_CALENDAR_ID>/<ICLOUD_EVENT_ID>.ics HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic <AUTHDATA>
Depth: 1
Prefer: return-minimal
Host: p31-caldav.icloud.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.2.2 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.2) GCDHTTPRequest
```

Response:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.11.2//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Australia/Sydney
X-LIC-LOCATION:Australia/Sydney
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:18950201T000000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:18950201T000000
TZNAME:AEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+100452
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19170101T000100
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19170101T000100
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19420101T020000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19420927T020000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19431003T020000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19861019T020000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20000827T020000
TZNAME:AEDT
TZOFFSETFROM:+1000
TZOFFSETTO:+1100
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19170325T020000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19170325T020000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19420329T020000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19720227T030000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19820404T030000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20060402T030000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20070325T030000
TZNAME:AEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19430328T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19440325T150000Z;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:AEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19710101T000000
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19710101T000000
TZNAME:AEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+1000
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19711031T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19851026T160000Z;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:AEDT
TZOFFSETFROM:+1000
TZOFFSETTO:+1100
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19730304T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19810228T160000Z;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:AEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19830306T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19850302T160000Z;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:AEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19860316T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19890318T160000Z;BYDAY=3SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:AEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19871025T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19991030T160000Z;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:AEDT
TZOFFSETFROM:+1000
TZOFFSETTO:+1100
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19900304T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19950304T160000Z;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:AEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19960331T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=20050326T160000Z;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:AEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20011028T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=20071027T160000Z;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:AEDT
TZOFFSETFROM:+1000
TZOFFSETTO:+1100
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20080406T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=4
TZNAME:AEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20081005T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:AEDT
TZOFFSETFROM:+1000
TZOFFSETTO:+1100
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20160331T004928Z
UID:86ABADB9-CDC3-45D0-B932-5420DC10390A
DTEND;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20160425T093000
SUMMARY:Sample Event
DTSTART;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20160425T073000
DTSTAMP:20160509T000541Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20160408T220749Z
SEQUENCE:1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-APPLE-TRAVEL-ADVISORY-BEHAVIOR:AUTOMATIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Can you add the iCalendar of the event? Are u sure that u query the right calendar?

Comment: Positive that I'm on the correct calendar as I can retrieve a single event from that calendar using a GET request; it's just REPORT requests that don't seem to work for me

Comment: Add the iCalendar returned by GET to your Q

Comment: I've added it - event ID comes from exporting ics file from OS X Calendar App then reading its ID and adding it to the request

Comment: As it looks unusual - just to be sure, you are really querying two days - not one, from 5/24-5/26? Because your 4/25 event actually is 4/24 in UTC ...

Comment: Correct; I'll narrow it down at a later date; here, I'm just ensuring that I capture the Sample Event I've created

Comment: Comparing your request to what Calendar.app sends over you're missing a couple of HTTP headers -  "Content-Type: text/xml" may be required. And you're missing the xml declaration from the beginning of your XML payload (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>).

Comment: @Jamie Did you ever solve this? I had a working system as of a few weeks ago and now (with nothing changed on client side) I get the same response while PUTing changes and GETing single events still works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like `Depth: 2`. You probably want `Depth: 1`.

Check: [RFC2518](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc2518.html#HEADER_Depth)

Comment: Changed to depth 1, no change in result, but thanks for spotting anyway

Answer (score 1):

This is about the calendar provider implementation. The body of the request is completely fine, and seeing the event iCalendar representation, the response for the request should return the event.

The very only thing that I see that might be causing this is the `Prefer: return-minimal` header. Refer to [The "return-minimal" Preference](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-snell-http-prefer-13.html#return-minimal) to know more about it. The `calendar-query REPORT` is requesting just for the `calendar-data`. Normally the client requests for the `eTags`, so it checks if there are any difference between the calendars object it has and the ones in the server, if there is any different calendar object then the client sends a `CALDAV:calendar-multiget REPORT` with the `href` of the calendar objects that are differents.

Try it removing the `Prefer: return-minimal` header or instead try to change

```
<d:prop>
    <c:calendar-data />
</d:prop>
```

to

```
<d:prop>
    <d:getetag />
</d:prop>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That return-minimal is the cause is rather unlikely, but just querying the etag is a very good suggestion. It is quite possible that the server only supports a subset of the properties for a time range query.

Comment: I know is rather unlikely to happens, but using that header requesting for `calendar-data` has no sense, because the response for that won't be minimal at all. That's why I think he should either remove the header an ask for the `calendar-data` or ask for the `eTags` with the same header.

Comment: It makes no sense to specify the header for getetag either, since this property "always" exists. It is mostly useful for the calendar collection as those have a less uniform properties.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, try to only ask for the etag and then use the answered urls for a calendar-multiget REPORT.

I can recommended to you to use fiddler or any other program so you can see the requests and responses clearly. Also try to watch the requests from other clients like emClient for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Method-: REPORT
Content type-: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Header -: Depth : 1
URL-:GET /<ICLOUD_USER_ID>/calendars/
Set credentials
Following is RequestContent-:
<C:calendar-query xmlns:D='DAV:'
                 xmlns:C='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
                                     <D:prop>
                                       <D:getetag/>
                                       <C:calendar-data>
                                         <C:comp name='VCALENDAR'>
                                           <C:prop name='VERSION'/>
                                           <C:comp name='VEVENT'>
                                             <C:prop name='SUMMARY'/>
                                             <C:prop name='DESCRIPTION'/>
                                             <C:prop name='STATUS'/>
                                              <C:prop name='TRANSP'/>
                                               <C:prop name='ATTENDEE'/>
                                             <C:prop name='UID'/>
                                             <C:prop name='DTSTART'/>
                                             <C:prop name='DTEND'/>
                                             <C:prop name='DURATION'/>
                                             <C:prop name='RRULE'/>
                                             <C:prop name='RDATE'/>
                                             <C:prop name='EXRULE'/>
                                             <C:prop name='EXDATE'/>
                                             <C:prop name='RECURRENCE-ID'/>
                                           </C:comp>
                                         </C:comp>
                                       </C:calendar-data>
                                     </D:prop>
                                     <C:filter>
       <C:comp-filter name='VCALENDAR'>
         <C:comp-filter name='VEVENT'>
           <C:time-range start='20160524T000000Z'
                         end='20160526T000000Z'/>
         </C:comp-filter>
       </C:comp-filter>
     </C:filter>
                                   </C:calendar-query>
```

I think problem is with URL and method used. Use URL till calendars i.e /ICLOUD_USER_ID/calendars/ and method should be REPORT.